# What is this [blocking] tag?

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tags

The [blocking](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/blocking) tag has 113 questions, covering

- Firewall blocking (probably redundant with [ip-blocking](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ip-blocking))
- Undeliverable e-mail
- blocking IO
- resource limits

There is no tag wiki at all.

What should be done to clean up this mess?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It looks like a tag that should be burninated to me.

[image]

Comment: It's the only way to be sure!  http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/walkingdead/images/3/30/269209_kill-it-with-fire.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20150421064045

Comment: THIS is the only way to be sure: http://nukeitfromorbit.com.